# HtmlHelper.TextBox uses the model value even when an explicit value provided

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, html-helper

In a view I'm using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492984(v=vs.108)) of `HtmlHelper.TextBox`:

```c#
public static MvcHtmlString TextBox(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string name,
    Object value
)
```

The documentation states:

> *value*
>
> > Type: `System.Object`
> >
> > The value of the text input element. **If this value is `null`**, the value of the element is retrieved from the `ViewDataDictionary` object. If no value exists there, the value is retrieved from the `ModelStateDictionary` object.

I do provide a `value` when I call this overload, and this value is not null. Nevertheless, the value for the textbox is retrieved from the `ModelStateDictionary` whenever it is present there.

In order to force the textbox to use the value provided inline, I have to reset the model first in the controller (or remove the key with the textbox's name from the keys collection).

Same applies to other controls rendered by `HtmlHelper`.

Where is my understanding wrong? Or is that a bug in the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ModelState` always has precedence in all input helpers, not just `TextBox`. This allows you to specify a default value in the view, and after POST render the posted value (taken from ModelState) without having to manually pass the posted value to the view. To use a different value you must remove the entry from ModelState.

Comment: Yes, this is what I observe, but not what is documented to happen. Hence the question.

Comment: The documentation [has been fixed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textbox?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_InputExtensions_TextBox_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_Object_) to say, "The value is retrieved in this order - the `ModelStateDictionary` object, the value of this parameter, the `ViewDataDictionary` object, and lastly, a value attribute in the html attributes."

Answer (score 1):

This is how the model binder works, it takes the values from the modelstate, probably to preserve the values from a failed postback or validation failure.  Have you tried using the Html attributes to set the value

```
Html.TextBox("Id", new { Value = Model.Id})
```

Si

Comment: Yes, I know how the model binding works. It just seems odd to me that how it works apparently is not how it is documented to work.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help.

Using viewmodel with property below and ViewData["textboxvalue"]

```
public string Id { get; set; }
```

If you have provided an object that can be bound into the "value" parameter, the the html helper will always use its value.

-Text box value bound to view model - these show the model's id

```
@Html.TextBox("Id", Model.Id)
```

-Text box with provided value from view data - these show the view data's value

```
@Html.TextBox("Id", ViewData["textboxvalue"])
```

Even if the name provided is not the same as the property name, the value will still be that provided by the model

-Text box value bound to view model - these show the model's id

```
@Html.TextBox("Id2", Model.Id)
```

-Text box with provided value from view data - these show the view data's value

```
@Html.TextBox("Id2", ViewData["textboxvalue"])
```

If you provide your own custom

-Text box with provided hardcoded value - this shows the string provided in view

```
@Html.TextBox("Id", "my hardcoded value in view")
```

The documentation is stating - if you do not populate the "value" parameter, as in the below:

```
@Html.TextBox("Id", null)
```

Then mvc framework will automatically try and search both the model that is bound to the view and the data dictionary.

If you have this case, then

-Found a property called "Id" in view model.  Text box value set to the model's value

```
@Html.TextBox("Id", null)
```

But if the "name" value is not a property/key in the model/dictionaries, then the framework could not find any value, so the text box value will be an empty string

-Text box with name that is not property in view model or view data

```
@Html.TextBox("Id2", null)
```